# Full width input and label inside of a list

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down list that has a series of checkboxes + labels. Which looks a little something like:

```
<div class="triggerHome">
    <div class="trigger">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <label>Label</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <label>Label</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <label>Label</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the label doesn't span across the entire width of the container. So there's a lot of white space where the user is unable to click.

I could use a javascript / jquery solution, but I would prefer if I could solve this using only CSS:

```
$('li').click(function(e) {
   $(this).children
   ('input[type=checkbox]').trigger('click');
});
```

**[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/zA76z/5/)**

Comment: Make your labels into blocks:

use the : display: block; property and give them width if you have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the label on the same line as the checkbox, use `display:inline-block;` and define a width as Hristo said.  Wrap the `input` and give that a width as well, remove the `padding-right` from the `li`

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/zA76z/8/)

```
    <li for="manage-locations-minnesota">
        <div class="tenPercent">
            <input id="manage-locations-minnesota" type="checkbox" name="manage-locations-minnesota" value="false">
        </div>
        <label for="manage-locations-minnesota">Minnesota</label>
    </li>
```

add/change CSS:

```
.right-label label {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:90%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    left: 5px; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tenPercent {
    float:left;
    width:10%;
}

.custom-dropdown li {
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid #7b95a1;
  padding: 9px 0 9px 18px; }
```

Comment: I guess this would only work if I reworked some of my CSS so that it would be using margin on the children instead of padding on the container, and I would need another container for my input checkbox so that it could fill up the other 10% of the width.

Comment: or just add a media query for the screen width that causes the line to break and change the width percentage a bit.

Comment: It's not a line break that's an issue. The content of the li must be %100 at all times.

In your solution, even at desktop resolution the li content doesn't equal a full width. 90% + 40px (or whatever the checkbox is) still leaves a slight margin that wouldn't be clickable.

Comment: you can just wrap the input and get rid of the padding right on the li causing the right edge of the label to not be clickable.  i'll update the answer